# Defining the range and domain of Composite functions as well as plotting graphs of composite functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

Consider a function $$f(x)=\vert{\vert {x-3} \vert -2}\vert$$ for $0\le x\le 4$

And $$g(x)= 4-\vert {2-x}\vert$$ for $-1\le x\le 3$

Where $\vert .\vert$ represents modulus function.

Now the problem is that I want to draw the graph of $f(g(x))$.

Now I could make cases by the finding the critical points of the modulus functions and then plot the graph. But this seems to be a very tedious task. I want to know if there is any other way to plot the graph of such composite functions without taking so much of cases.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$\mathbf {Edit :} $

CY Aries' method seems to be very appropriate for this question but what if the question asks for some cubic or quadratic function. e. g. 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1+x^3,  & \text{$x\le 0$} \\
x^2-1, & \text{$x\ge 0$}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
(x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}},  & \text{$x\le 0$} \\
(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}, & \text{$x\ge 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Then plot $g(f(x))$. Now that method won't work here. I am also supposed to define the non-uniform function $g(f(x))$

Comment: what can you use to draw the functions?

Comment: sorry, i meant a program for instance

Comment: it is ok, so you must use a pen and a sheet of paper?

Comment: Yes and It would be much helpful if you algebraically state a method for graphing but still it's fine

Comment: So you want to plot imaginary numbers (as in the cube root of negative values of $x$)?

Comment: You mean to say square root of negative values I guess Which I don't think would possibly happen in any case of g(f(x))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) The graph of $y=2-x$

[image]

(ii) Taking the modulus function means flipping everything below the $x$-axis to the upper half-plane. The graph of $y=|2-x|$

[image]

(iii) The graph of $y=-|2-x|$

[image]

(iv) The graph of $y=g(x)=-|2-x|+4$

[image]

(v) The graph of $y=g(x)-3$

[image]

(vi) The graph of $y=|g(x)-3|$

[image]

(vii) The graph of $y=|g(x)-3|-2$

[image]

(viii) The graph of $f(g(x))=||g(x)-3|-2|$

[image]

If the domain is the set of all real numbers, the graph will be

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since graphing is generally done by computer, here's the simple solution in *Mathematica*:

```
f[x_] := Abs[Abs[x - 3] - 2];
g[x_] := 4 - Abs[2 - x];
Plot[f[g[x]], {x, -4, 8}]
```

[image: f[g[x]]]

Comment: Perhaps a fractal structure like the Weierstrass function can emerge when the function is plugged in recursively.

Answer (score 1):

My method is before dividing the real line into intervals, find the critical points first. What are the critical points of $f(x)$? These are $|x-3|=0,2$, i.e., $x=1,3,5$.

Now for $f(g(x))$ these critical points correspond to $g(x)=4-|2-x|=1,3,5$. Since $5$ can be excluded because $g(x)\leq 4$, the critical points are $|x-2|=0,1,3$, which are $x=-1,1,2,3,5$.

Now you can graph the function $f(g(x))$, which is piecewise linear, by joining the dots $(x,f(g(x)))$ for these critical points.